# Filter list based on more than one field

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm iterating a list of jobs and there's a search implemented on this list.
Search is working but now it only filters list based on one field.

Here's my list:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let job of allJobs | search : searchTerm">
    <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
        <div>
            <span> {{job.day | uppercase}}</span>
            <span> {{job.month | uppercase}}</span>
        </div>
        </ion-col>

        <ion-col>
        <div>
            <span>{{job.time}}</span>
            <span>{{job.name}}</span>
        </div>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-card>
```

I made a pipe for implementing search. Here's the code for it.

```
  transform(items: any[], terms: string): any[] {
    if(!items) return [];
    if(!terms) return items;
    terms = terms.toLowerCase();
    return items.filter( it => {
      return it.name.toLowerCase().includes(terms); // only filter name
    });
  }
```

Now the list gets filtered only based on the `name` field. I wanna filter the list based on `day`, `month` and `time` as well.

Can anyone tell me how to make this happen?

Sample Data for Jobs. Jobs is an array of objects

```
   [  
      {  
         "id":10,
         "day":"Monday",
         "month":"June",
         "time":"10",
         "name":"John",
         "email":"john@gmail.com"
      },
      {  
         "id":11,
         "day":"Tuesday",
         "month":"May",
         "time":"12",
         "name":"Jane",
         "email":"jane@gmail.com"
      },
      {  
         "id":12,
         "day":"Friday",
         "month":"June",
         "time":"16",
         "name":"",
         "email":"john@gmail.com"
      },
      {  
         "id":13,
         "day":"Tuesday",
         "month":"August",
         "time":"21",
         "name":"",
         "email":"kevin@gmail.com"
      },
      {  
         "id":14,
         "day":"Saturday",
         "month":"December",
         "time":"12",
         "name":"Sam",
         "email":"sam@gmail.com"
      },

   ]
```

And `searchTerm` is just a string.

As you can see, there are more fields in the sample data than the one displayed in the HTML but I'm trying only to search for the fields that are displayed in the HTML. Some fields can have null values (for eg. `name` in the sample data has two null values)

I tried the solutions already provided but none of them are working for my requirement.

P.S: Read somewhere that pipes are not the best option to do functionality like this. I'm ready to implement this logic in the class as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code.. it's pretty simple.

```
  transform(items: any[], terms: string): any[] {
    if (!items) return [];
    if (!terms) return items;
    terms = terms.toLowerCase();
    terms = terms.trim();
    return items.filter(it => {
      if (it.day) {
        return it.day.toLowerCase().includes(terms);
      }
      if (it.month) {
        return it.month.toLowerCase().includes(terms);
      }
      if (it.time) {
        return it.time.toLowerCase().includes(terms);
      }
      if (it.name) {
        return it.name.toLowerCase().includes(terms);
      }
    });
  }
```

If your JSON has null values, you can replace it with an empty string using the following code:

```
items = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(items).replace(/null/g, '""'));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try combining your `includes` with the [logical or-operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description) (`||`):

```
transform(items: any[], terms: string): any[] {
    if (!items) return [];
    if (!terms) return items;
    terms = terms.toLowerCase();
    return items.filter(it => {
      return it.name.toLowerCase().includes(terms) ||
        it.day.toLowerCase().includes(terms) ||
        it.month.toLowerCase().includes(terms) ||
        it.time.toLowerCase().includes(terms)
    });
}
```

This statement will return true if any of the `includes` returns true. So basically any item which `name`, `day`, `month` or `time` contains the searchterm will be returned by the pipe.

This solution assumes that `name`, `day`, `month` and `time` are not null or undefined. But I'm assuming that is okay as your sample data suggests null values will be empty strings(`""`). If my assumption is not correct you'll have to check if the values are assigned, before accessing them.

Answer (score 1):

This dont work because the `includes` dont test for multiple term cases. You didnt say whats inside the `items Array` but if it is a String you could do this:

```
transform(items: any[], terms: string): any[] {
    if(!items) return [];
    if(!terms) return items;
    terms = terms.toLowerCase();
    return items.filter( it => {
      //if it is something like "Programmer 07 November 12:00PM"
      var informations = it.split(' '); //["Programmer", "07" ,"November" ,"12:00PM"]
      var termArray = terms.split(' ');
      var rightResult = true;
      for (var index in termArray) {
       if !(informations.include(termArray[index])) {
         rightResult = false;
       }
       return rightResult;


    });
  }
```

Comment: Tried your code. It's not working. I have updated the code with sample data

Answer (score 1):

Inside your transform method of your search pipe, apply filters on all the fields you want to apply filter on. Following will search for all keys in the object:

```
transform(items: any[], terms: string): any[] {
    if(!items) return [];
    if(!terms) return items;
    terms = terms.toLowerCase();
    return items.filter( it => {

       return keys(it).reduce((prev, key) => {
          return prev || key.toLowerCase().includes(term);
       }, false);
    });
}
```

If keys or Object.keys are not working, use the following code instead of reduce function:

```
...
let bInclude = false;
for(let key in it){
  bInclude = bInclude || key.toLowerCase().includes(term);
}

return bInclude;
...
```

Comment: ERROR ReferenceError: keys is not defined @Shubham Chaudhary

Comment: Use Object.keys instead. @Annabelle

Comment: Tried that but it's still not working @Shubham Chaudhary

Comment: Edited the answer, use for..in for getting object keys as array

Comment: Tried your code. Its still not working. I have sample data and updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

filterItems(param: any): void {
let val: string = param;

```
if (val) {
  if (val.trim() !== '') {
    this.filterItemsList = this.items.filter((data) => {
      console.log(data.category);
      return data.category.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1
        || data.products.some(product => product.code.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    })
  }
}
```

}

it's working perfect

Comment: this.searcgResinput = res;
    this.searcgDatainput =  this.searcgResinput.data;
    this.searcgDatainput = this.searcgDatainput.filter((user) => {
      //console.log("check ",user.customer_name);
      return (user.customer_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.input.toLowerCase()) > -1 || user.dsr_no.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.input.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    })                                                                          




using || pipe line u have to search more then one field