# Full search on page include hidden text from UI

Tags: ionic-framework, search, ionic3

How to implement the search when I type in the search bar? It may search anything is visible and non visible to the user.

Visible can be the code, name, number, item etc.
Non-visible can be the image description e.g. Heineken (2nd item image)

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your code so far? What have you tried to do?

Comment: I have totally no idea how to do that, can you help?

Comment: You could implement a search pipe as described in question and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53185106/5730444)...