# ionic 3 multi level search filter

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, filtering

I want to implement search function for multilevel array. I have bind the following data to `this.items` (refer to image). Then I use the following TS code to filter. It can filter the `category` level but not into the `products` level.

How to filter the `code` which is in the `products` array? Same goes for `desc` and `uom` too if possible. For example in the image, you see 7 items, if all 7 items not exist in the search, the entire category will not display. If one or move items exist then it will display.

**HTML**

`<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" (ionInput)="filterItems($event.target.value)"></ion-searchbar>`

**TS file**

```
filterItems(param: any): void {
    let val: string = param;

    if (val) {
      if (val.trim() !== '') {
        this.filterItemsList = this.items.filter((data) => {
          console.log(data.category);
          return data.category.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        })
      }
    }
}
```

**Image**
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/danrevah/ngx-pipes#filterby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53326441/5730444) you can combine different conditions with the logical OR-operator. Using this and the [`some` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) you could try something like:

```
filterItems(param: any): void {
    let val: string = param;

    if (val) {
      if (val.trim() !== '') {
        this.filterItemsList = this.items.filter((data) => {
          console.log(data.category);
          return data.category.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1
            || data.products.some(product => product.code.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

---

How does this work?

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

So we can easily test if any of your products has a code which contains the search value. You can do this for your other properties aswell, joining them with the logical OR (`||`) again like for `desc` and so on:

```
return data.category.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1
        || data.products.some(product => product.code.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1)
        || data.products.some(product => product.desc.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
```

Comment: Yes I saw your answer on the other topic before, but it just filtering 1 level. Mine needs 2 level e.g. `product -> product.code`. Thanks for your help